# Struggling to grab data from website using python

Tags: python, wget, urlopen

I'm trying to grab snowfall data from the National Weather Service at this site:

https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/

The data can be downloaded via the webpage with a 'click' on the file type in the drop down, but I can't seem to figure out how to automate this using python. They have an ftp archive, but it requires a login and I can't access it for some reason.

However, since the files can be downloaded via a "click" on the webpage interface, I imagine there must be a way to grab it using wget or urlopen? But I can't seem to figure out what the exact url address would be in this case in order to use those functions.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to download this data straight from the website listed above?

Thanks!

Comment: Clicking the link runs the javascript function `download_data()`. You should be able to examine the source of that function and determine what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect links with Chrome Console.

Press F12, then click on file type:

[image]

Here an URL `https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/data/202112/sfav2_CONUS_6h_2021122618_grid184.nc`

You can download it with python using [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/data/202112/sfav2_CONUS_6h_2021122618_grid184.nc')

data = r.content # file context
```

Or you can just save it to file with [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = 'https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/data/202112/sfav2_CONUS_6h_2021122618_grid184.nc'
dst = 'data.nc'
urlretrieve(url, dst)
```

Comment: @nluchett Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: How do I mark it as accepted? I dont see that function? Thanks

Comment: @nluchett You can press grey checkmark here near the answer https://prnt.sc/24x273e